# CentOS 6 Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, centos6

After installing owncloud and running the MySQL secure setup I can not connect to the server anymore. I get the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ username$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 root@x.x.x.x -v
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/authorized_keys2 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/authorized_keys2-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Whats going on and how can I fix it? I still have an active conneciton to the server

Comment: check the logs. It looks like tcp_wrappers (`/etc/hosts.allow`, `/etc/hosts.deny`) issue.

Comment: grep sshd /etc/hosts.allow returns nothing and same for deny

Comment: Don't grep there. There are few lines. Post them to the edited question. Also post recent logs from your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/log/messages file and see what the error message is. In many case it just a misconfiguration of permission.